# How can I use a CASE condition based on a junction table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Product table, and a ProductRep table. Products all have status types.

```
ProductID
StatusID

tbl_Product
```

-

```
RepID
ProductID

tbl_ProductRep
```

I'm passing the status parameter to a stored procedure, and querying products based on that:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Product p
WHERE p.Status = CASE WHEN(ISNULL(@Status, '') = '') THEN p.Status
                      ELSE @Status END
AND p.Available = 1
AND p.AuthorizedID = @CurrentUserID
```

As you can see above, I'm defaulting to whatever the record is if @Status returns empty.

What I want to do is add a "fake" status, to tell the procedure when I want to return products that don't have any reps assigned to them. So a "fake" status for that could be 0.

Pseudo Logic

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Product p
WHERE p.Status = CASE WHEN(ISNULL(@Status, '') = '') THEN p.Status
                      WHEN(@Status = 0) THEN p.Status
                      ELSE @Status END
AND p.Available = 1
AND p.AuthorizedID = @CurrentUserID

AND IF @Status = 0 then only return products that don't have a rep in the junction table.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Product p
WHERE   
    (
        (
            p.Status = CASE WHEN(ISNULL(@Status, '') = '') THEN p.Status ELSE @Status END
        )
        OR  
        (
            Status = 0 AND ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID FROM tbl_ProductRep
        )
    )
AND p.Available = 1
AND p.AuthorizedID = @CurrentUserID
```

This should give you your original result, but if you pass the fake Status, it would bring back all items that are not in the `tbl_ProductRep` table

Comment: As soon as I saw your answer I realized I needed to edit my question slightly. I have a few more conditions (ANDS) that are involved, which complicates that final OR, unless I? Apologies... I should have been more clear.

Comment: Please let us know once you have chnaged the question, so that we can review.

Comment: Hmm. What about using the old order of operation with some extra parenthesis? - AND ((@Status = 0 AND ProductID NOT IN (...)) OR @Status <> 0 AND ProductID IN (...)) ... or maybe that won't work. Confusing.

Comment: And I could break it out into IF @Status = 0 BEGIN END ELSE... But wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Actually that string of (((()))) might actually be working. Testing it now.

Comment: Its going to boil down to where you put the parenthesis, and what the intended logic should be. I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Those parenthesis can get confusing :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear on exactly what you want, but another option maybe something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Product p
WHERE   
    1 = CASE WHEN @Status = 0 THEN CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_ProductRep r WHERE r.ProductID = p.ProductID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            WHEN ISNULL(@Status, '') = '' THEN 1
            WHEN @Status = p.Status THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
            END 
AND p.Available = 1
AND p.AuthorizedID = @CurrentUserID
```